# SQL Server CE SDF file corrupt. Fixing schema and understanding the repair log file

Tags: sql-server-ce, corruption, logfile, data-recovery

I have received a corrupt `.SDF` file from a client. I used `SqlCeEngine.engine` method to allow me to repair it to the point where I can connect to the database file and view the schema. It has also recovered some of the data. Although the main table which I have called `TableA` is empty.

It created a log file which seems to be printing out all the rows it could not recover... the interesting point is the "invalid number of columns". About 2 years ago a schema update was pushed out adding 3 new columns.

When I checked the schema on the now recovered `.SDF` file it was missing these 3 columns. So I am assuming the schema has corrupted as well and the recovery method is trying to reinsert rows but it doesn't match the table schema any more. I find it odd that it cannot recover these three columns.

Can anyone explain more fully what is going on with the log file?

I am guessing there is no way of adding the missing columns first and then repairing it, so the rows match possible recovering more data from that table?

Many thanks.

The log file only contains reference to TableA, and there are only two types of entry. Snippet of the log file:

```
Block page not found - pwszTable: TableA, idPage: 1465
Block page not found - pwszTable: TableA, idPage: 1465
Invalid number of columns in the row - idPage: 1061, iSlot: 7, cRowCols: 22,       cTableCols: 25
Invalid number of columns in the row - idPage: 1061, iSlot: 8, cRowCols: 22,       cTableCols: 25
```

Comment: Make sure to use the very latest runtime version on the PC where you try to repair

Comment: @ErikEJ, the latest version is SQLCE4SP1, isn't it?

Comment: @iljon - there is actually a hotfix out for 4.0 SP1: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2016/02/sql-server-compact-40-sp1-hotfix.html